# InertiaJS React Props undefined

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-props, breeze, inertiajs

I'm trying to send props from my laravel route to my react component, but the props in the component is returning undefined, here's my route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return Inertia::render('OurDashboard', [
            'user' => Auth::user(),
        ]);
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

and here is part of my component OurDashboard.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Sidebar from '../Components/Sidebar';
import FrontPage from '../Components/Pages/FrontPage';

export default function Dashboard({ user }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter' }}>
      <Sidebar>
        <FrontPage />
      </Sidebar>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I've only worked with inertia in a previous personal project and there sending props like this worked.

I did try to use Usepage but gave up, it only made my problem more complex.